# Align viewport view to object/Move object to viewport view

Tags: modeling, workflow, objects

How do I align the viewport view so it is looking out of a selected object? How do I move an object to the viewport's view? This would be useful for placing some objects like lights where the viewport "camera" is, or aligning one object to another.

Comment: [How to lock the view to prevent rotation of the view camera?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/356/12), [Can I lock the viewport to always jump to what is currently selected?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/4923/12).

Comment: What are those links for? Are you proposing those as a possible duplicates? Well they are **completely** unrelated to this.

Comment: Pretty sure I didn't say anything.. they are related so I posted them.

Comment: Okay, I was just making sure you weren't calling it a duplicate of those. Hopefully this answer helps some people out, as I found it a useful trick I recently discovered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Viewport to object**
To align the viewport to the object, select your desired object and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Numpad0</kbd>. This sets the selected object as the active viewport camera. Hit <kbd>Numpad0</kbd> to return to your normal view, and return back to the object view again with the same key. Repeat this procedure on the camera when you are done in order to use the camera as normal.

**Object to viewport**
To align the object to the viewport, first set the desired object as your active camera and return to your view (steps above), then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Numpad0</kbd> to snap the object set as your active camera to your current viewport view. You can also fly the view with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> to move the object around with the view. You may need to enter wireframe mode by hitting <kbd>Z</kbd> (while not in fly mode) in order to see.

This is the same process you may already be familiar with when aligning the camera, but it also works on other objects.